# How can I draw blank lines in tables?

Tags: tables, outlines

I'm trying to recreate the following table:

[image]

But I have problems with the first two columns. I don’t want the vertical lines to go all the way up.

[image]

How can I limit the extension of the vertical lines?

Here's the code I'm using.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\def\arraystretch{1.3}
    \caption{Caption}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-8}
& & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Datos principales}\\
\cline{3-8}
& & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Datos 1} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Datos 2}\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Primer grupo} & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\

\cline{2-8}
                              & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\cline{2-8}
                              & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Segundo grupo} & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-8}
                              & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\cline{2-8}
                              & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \label{tab:my_label}

\end{table}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{}`? Note that resizing the content by scaling the box will lead to inconsistencies in font sizes, line spacing and line widths between different tables and between tables and other document elements. It's better to use a standard font-sizing command such as `\small` and/or make other adjustments.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `\resizebox` unless you want to signal to your readers that you have nothing but contempt for them.

Comment: Using ``boxes'' as a format for tables is not a good standard. Use horizontal lines to sections your tables. The package booktabs provides a good standard for formatting tables.,

Comment: what should i use then? i;m new to latex

Comment: @PeterJansson There is no standard in typography. Yes is best to minimize the `furniture` but it depends on the type of table. Put them if it enhances readability and leave them off, f they have no impact. We are not at war with vertical lines are we?

Comment: @yannisl "there is no standard in typography" is a vague truth since there IS a standard typography in all or at least most languages.

Comment: @PeterJansson Unfortunately no, there is no standard! Can you provide a link to a standard? There are plenty of recommended ways and publishers guides but no standard.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use a couple of `\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}` directives to fix the immediate formatting problem; see the first table below.

I would further like to suggest that you give a table a simultaneously more-compact yet also more-open look, by getting rid of all vertical rules -- trust me, they won't be missed -- and using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules. Placing repeated pieces of information in the table's header is also a good idea; see the second table below. Note that because there are no vertical lines to begin with in this approach, there's also no need to apply the `\multicolumn{2}{l|}{}` kludge.

A final remark: I can see no reason whatsoever for assaulting the table at hand with the `\resizebox` sledgehammer.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

%\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\caption{Caption1}
\label{tab:my_label1}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{2}{l|} *{6}{c|} }
\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} % empty double-wide cell, with "|" on the right
  & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Datos principales}\\
\cline{3-8}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} % empty double-wide cell, with "|" on the right
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Datos 1} 
  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Datos 2}\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Primer grupo}  
     & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-8}
     & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{2-8}
     & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Segundo grupo} 
     & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{2-8}
     & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{2-8}
     & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 

\bigskip\bigskip

\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt} % not needed for 2nd table
\caption{Caption2}
\label{tab:my_label2}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{l} *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Grupo & Prueba & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Datos principales}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-8}
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Datos 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Datos 2} \\
\midrule
Primer 
     & Primera & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
     & Segunda & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
     & Tercera & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\addlinespace
Segundo
     & Primera & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
     & Segunda & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
     & Tercera & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @IvanLeonParadaMarin Other remarks: `\label` comes immediately after `\caption`, and `[H]` has become `[ht]`.  If you really think you need `[H]`, then you probably want to get rid of `\begin{table}[H]` altogether and just use the caption or capt-of package.

Answer (score 3):

The `tabular` environment in LaTeX is based on the `\halign` TeX primitive. Each table item is created from a left material from the table declaration (there is vertical rule in the first column because you declared `|c`).

Then the table item data is printed and then the right material from the table declaration (there is a vertical rule in each column, because you declared `c|`). The left+right material can be omitted by the `\omit` TeX primitive. If you write `\omit` in the first column then the left and right vertical rule is omitted, and if you use `\omit` in another column, then the right vertical rule is omitted.

The part of your code without unwanted vertical rules can be managed by the `\omit` TeX primitive, like this:

```
\omit & & \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Datos principales}\\
\cline{3-8}
\omit & & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Datos 1} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Datos 2}\\
\hline
```

Comment: Of course it's much clearer with ``\multicolumn{2}{c|} & \multicolumn{6}{c|}{Datos principales} \\`` without dealing with the primitive `\omit`.

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` has the built-in feature `corners` to be used with `hvlines` to create this effect. The package also has features to make rows or columns in bold face. Note that **you must compile the document twice** when using `nicematrix` each time you make a change that affects the size of the cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\bfseries}cccccccc}[corners, hvlines]
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries}
& & \Block{1-6}{Datos principales}\\
& & \Block{1-3}{Datos 1} &&& \Block{1-3}{Datos 2}\\
\Block{3-1}{Primer\\grupo} & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
 & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\Block{3-1}{Segundo\\grupo} & Primera prueba & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 & Segunda prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
 & Tercera prueba & 4 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 6
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```